# Expected initializer before function name

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct sotrudnik {
    string name;
    string speciality;
    string razread;
    int zarplata;
}

sotrudnik create(string n,string spec,string raz,int sal) {
    sotrudnik temp;
    temp.name=n;
    temp.speciality=spec;
    temp.razread=raz;
    temp.zarplata=sal;
    return temp;
}
*sotrudnik str_compare (string str1, string str2, sotrudnik sot1, sotrudnik sot2)
```

I try to learn C++. But when i try to compile this code with GCC-4.4.5 by using the options " g++ -Wall -c ", I get the following error:

> g++ -Wall -c "lab2.cc" (in directory: /home/ion/Univer/Cpp)
>
> lab2.cc:11: error: expected initializer before `create`
>
> lab2.cc:20: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before `str_compare`
>
> Compilation failed.

Both errors are tied to the function declarations. (round 11 is the declaration of function create, round 20 - of the function `str_compare`). Tried to google for these kinds of errors, but couldn't find examples of similar errors, as the error messages are very generic. How can I understand their meaning and how to solve them? Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of your 'struct' definition.

Also,

```
*sotrudnik
```

needs to be

```
sotrudnik*
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I missed that.. anyway, the second error remains the same. Is it because is returns pointer to the structure type I created?

Comment: looks like this type of error happens when semicolons are missing, such mysterious c++.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a semi colon to the end of your structure:

```
 struct sotrudnik {
    string name;
    string speciality;
    string razread;
    int zarplata;
} //Semi colon here
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to suggest an edit to the original answer.